# Spring Batch - Commit Interval repeating Items

Tags: spring, spring-batch

My commit interval is 25, and it works fine when I have more than 25 items in my database. However, if I have, for example, only one item, it reads the same item 25 times. I don't know how can I change that. Anyone could help me?

```
public Step stepZero() { 
return StepBuilderFactory.get('stepZero')
.<ExampleEntity, ExampleEntity>chunk(25)
.reader(stepZeroReader)
.processor(stepZeroProcessor)
.writer(stepZeroWriter)
.transactionManager(transactionManagerPortal)
.listener(chunkListener())
.build();
}
```

Comment: That is probably due to how you have written your reader, please post it.